# Parsing Specific Phrase From String (T-Sql)

Tags: sql, t-sql, parsing

I have a field in a database w/ the structure below:

**File Number:**XXXXXXX
**User Name:**XXXXXXXX
**Check Number(s):**XXXXXXXXX
**Printer Location:**XXXXXXXXXXXXX

The Xs in the above example can be any set of characters

I need to extract the Check Number and Printer Location values (the Xs) from that string.

I am at a loss, any takers?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not enforce the structure with a proper schema?

Comment: use `charindex` twice, look for "Check Number(s):" and then "Printer Location:", then `substring` out the portion between, then use `RIGHT` to get the ending portion.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I need to head to a meeting, but I can give some direction.  The following gives you a flavor for what to do for check number:

```
select (case when fcn > 0
             then substring(f, fcn+21, charindex('<BR>', f, fcn)-fcn)
        end) as checknumber
from (select t.*, charindex('Check Number(s):</B>', f) as fcn
      from t
     ) t
```

The subquery just finds the location of the identifier, if any.  The outer query extracts the appropriate characters from the field.  The complication is calculating the length of the substring.

Note:  there may be off-by-1 errors in this since I'm not able to test it right now.

Comment: String parsing in T-SQL is so nasty.